# Remove Discord Markdown

Tags: discord.py

### How do I remove mark down in discord.py?

I was making an **eval command** but I realized that sending it with markdown ***eg.*** '```py print("example code")```', breaks it.

I want to make it easier for me and the other admin/mod to use it for debugging purposes in my bot.

````py
@client.command()
async def eval(ctx, *,  code):
    out, err = io.StringIO(), io.StringIO()
    sys.stdout = out
    sys.stderr = err

    await ctx.channel.trigger_typing()
    await aexec(code)

    results = out.getvalue()
    errors = err.getvalue()

    await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = "Eval", description=f"Output Is \n```bash\n{results}```"))
    await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = "Code", description=f"Input Is \n```py\n{code}```"))
````

the above code is what I've tried so far..

Comment: Make sure to only allow owner to use this since `eval` can be risky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been playing with your code for the past hours, I wanted to figured it out :P

This is the only way i could access the code when there was markdown in the command input.

````py
@client.command()
async def eval(ctx, *, code):
    raw = f'{ctx.message.content}'[12:-3] # Get rid of markdown + py and last 3 ```
    #Might want to add if statements in case the input doesn't include py / something else.
    print (raw) # Testing purpose
    out, err = io.StringIO(), io.StringIO()
    sys.stdout = out
    sys.stderr = err
    await ctx.channel.trigger_typing()
    exec(raw) # no need for await
 
    results = out.getvalue()
    errors = err.getvalue()
 
    await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = "Eval", description=f"Output Is \n```bash\n{results}```"))
    await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = "Code", description=f"Input Is \n```py\n{raw}```"))
    await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = "Errors", description=f"Errors are \n```py\n{errors}```")) #Added this output to see errors
````

Comment: Btw I tested the code and it keeps on deleting the first letters of the command I tried going for [8:-3] instead of [12:-3] and it worked :D